# Error: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**db.php**

```
class db {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, private
    function __construct() {
        try {
            $this - > _pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.config::get('mysql/host').
                '; dbname='.config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
            echo 'hello ';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e - > getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static
    function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new db();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

config.php

```
         class config {

public static function get($path=null) {
    if($path) {

        $config = $GLOBALS['config'] ;
        $path = explode('/',$path) ;


    foreach ($path as $bit) {
        if(isset($config[$bit])) { 
             $config = $config[$bit];
           }
       }

       return $config ;
    }

     } 
  }
```

initialize.php

```
   session_start() ;

     $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array (
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user' => 'root' ,
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'login' 
    ) ) ;
```

all three files added 
**Error**:

> in main db::getInstance()  call error shown  Error:  PDO::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string .

add more details for submitting. what lines i add to in  it submit question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of below

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host='.config::get('mysql/host').'; dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db') , config::get('mysql/username') ,config::get('mysql/password')) ;
```

Try

```
    <?php
$host = config::get('mysql/host');
$database = config::get('mysql/db');
$username = config::get('mysql/user');
$pasword = config::get('mysql/password');

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database', $username, $pasword);
?>
```

Comment: @leecarter he had an extra single quote.

Comment: still same problem occurred

Comment: @leecarter can you `echo $pasword = config::get('mysql/password');` and see if the password is showing here. I thing the variables are not passing into PDO connection

Comment: @anto.nishanth  nothing show there because i don't set password on DB

Comment: @leecarter glad it helped you